# Does bootstrap have any options config that can let the developer to configure the globle appearance of the application?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

its a Naive question however it keeps bugging me a lot. is there any way to configure stuff like colors, round to sharp corners of the elements and stuff like that. m aware of css and also know that these things can be easily taken care in css however it will be cool if there is some way i can provide just a few config params and see the overall appearance change.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this [link](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) to download a customized bootstrap version.